# How can I convert Unicode to utf8?

Tags: php, encoding, utf8mb4

I have a database full of Unicode strings and now I need a function to convert and show them.

This is my current string:

```
\u062f\u0648\u0646\u0647 \u0645\u0646\u2665\u2665\u2665\u2665
```

And this is expected output:

```
دونه من♥️♥️♥️♥️
```

Comment: change your column  datatype to `Blob` in database table its should show the what you outpput you expected

Comment: @AlbertAkki Actually I don't have access to the database,It's Off-the-shelf and I should retrieve values from it.

Comment: set php header then. like `<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
ini_set("default_charset", "UTF-8");
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
iconv_set_encoding("internal_encoding", "UTF-8");
iconv_set_encoding("output_encoding", "UTF-8"); ?>
` wherever you want to show the result

Comment: @AlbertAkki just tried but no use.

Comment: @ Hamidreza Noruzinejad, then i would suggest to make change in database table. just take access of database and change the datatype

Comment: @AlbertAkki Thanks, check my solution.

Comment: Where is `\u....` coming from?  If you can get that to be `UTF-8` instead, then several things will be simpler.

Comment: Is the column in the table declared `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`?  Without that, all the suggestions will be for naught.  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Eh?  I don't see any utf8mb4 here.  `\u....` is Unicode, not utf8mb4.  Maybe the title needs changing?

Comment: @RickJames you are right , thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})/',
function ($match) {
      return mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*', $match[1]), 'UTF-8', 'UCS-2BE');
        }, '\u062f\u0648\u0646\u0647 \u0645\u0646\u2665\u2665\u2665\u2665');
```

#### [Online Demo](https://3v4l.org/pSnOZ)